# HstResponse::addHeadElement has no effect

Tags: java, servlets, hippocms

I'm using [Hippo CMS](http://www.onehippo.com/).

After unsuccessfully using [HST SEO support plugin](http://hst-seo-support.forge.onehippo.org/), I realised that `HstResponse::addHeadElement` did not have any effect on my HTML pages.

For instance, when adding the following lines in a component's code:

```
Element title = response.createElement("title");
title.setTextContent("Foo");
response.addHeadElement(title, "hst.seo.document.title");
```

I would expect the corresponding `<title>Foo</title>` markup to be included in the response, but it is not.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I didn't have an appropriate `hst:headContributions` node in the layout file.

I had two of them for two different categories:

```
<hst:headContributions xhtml="true" categoryIncludes="headerNav" />
```

and

```
<hst:headContributions xhtml="true" categoryIncludes="styles" />
```

But the plugin doesn't use any category for its head contributions.

Adding the following line in my JSP template fixed the issue:

```
<hst:headContributions xhtml="true" categoryExcludes="headerNav,styles" />
```